# Problem with sidewaystable in Springer journal template file

Tags: tables, sv-classes, sidewaystable

I am using the Springer journal template and I need to print some of my tables in landscape form. It seems the template does not support the `sidewaystable`. Does anyone know how could I solve this? This is my code:

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable,verbatim}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\begin{sidewaystable}[ph!]
\centering
\footnotesize
\caption{Comparison of the performances of the LNS approach and MIP formulation on small-size instances}
\begin{tabular}{|c||cc|c|c|cc|cc|cc|cc|}
\hline
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Instance}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{OBJ} & Gap (\%) & Diff (\%) & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ CPU(s)} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$C_{max}$(h)} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$C_{avg}$(h)} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$TD$(km)}\\ 
& MIP & LNS  &  MIP & LNS & MIP & LNS &  MIP & LNS &  MIP & LNS &  MIP & LNS\\ 
\hline
\hline
L-M01R02S3 & *** & *** &  0 &  0 & $<1$ & 2 & 1.81 & 1.81 & 1.17 & 1.17 & 51.7 &  51.7\\
L-M01R02S4 & *** & *** & 0 &  0 &$<1$ & 2 &  2.1 &  2.1 & 1.25  & 1.25 & 71.8 &  71.8 \\
L-M01R02S5 & *** & *** & 0 & 0 &$<1$ & 2 &  2.46 & 2.46 & 1.22 & 1.22 & 70.7 & 70.7\\
L-M01R02S6 & *** & *** & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 &  2.96 & 2.96 & 1.19 & 1.19 & 68.7 & 68.7\\
L-M02R02S6 & *** & ***  & 0 & 0 & 5 & 6 & 1.73 & 1.73 & 0.94 & 0.94 & 67.1 & 67.1 \\
L-M02R02S7 & *** & *** & 0 &  0 & 20 & 5 & 1.71  & 1.71 & 0.67 & 0.67 & 69.2 & 69.2\\
L-M02R02S8 & *** & *** &  0 &  0 & 182 & 5 & 1.7 & 1.7 & 0.77 & 0.77 & 75 & 75\\
L-M02R02S9 & *** & *** & 28.45 &  0 & 1800 & 101 &  2.72 & 2.72 &  1.32 & 1.32 & 120 & 120\\
L-M02R02S10 & *** & *** & 40.49 &  0 & 1800 & 102 & 2.99 & 2.99 & 1.38 & 1.38 & 129.6 & 129.6\\
L-M02R02S11 & *** & *** & 50 & -0.1  & 1800 & 113 & 2.67 & 2.67  & 1.22 & 1.22 & 110 & 110 \\
L-M02R02S12 & *** & *** & 58.49 & -1.83 & 1800 & 124 & 2.8 & 2.4 & 1.11 & 1.09 & 156 & 164.2\\
M-M04R02S27 & *** & *** & * & -27.75 & 1800 & 139 & 2.97 & 2.96 & 1.52 & 1.19 & 274.8 & 226.7\\
M-M08R02S36 & *** & *** & * & -34.59 & 1800 & 166 & 2.99 & 2.78 & 1.17 & 1.05 & 475.2 & 399.6\\
M-M12R02S46 & *** & *** & * & -71.86 & 1800 & 124 & 2.93 & 1.73 & 1.68 & 0.62 & 737.7 & 323.4\\
H-M16R02S59 & *** & *** & * & -69.98 & 1800 & 145 & 2.96 & 1.98 & 1.6 & 0.77 & 752.7 & 560.2\\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{SAvsM}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

this is the address of the journal template:https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-general-template-file-for-the-latex-package-svjour3-for-springer-journals/pbbwqhxxvtbp

Comment: Why do you think so? Your document compiles perfectly.

Comment: @Pieter did you copy my code in the journal's template? The template's address is also copied at the end of my question. When I compile it the table does not show up in the landscape form.

Comment: I copied the template and then copied your code in the same directory as a separate file, and compiled that.

Comment: Hmm, when I compile your test document, the tabular material ends up getting placed largely outside of the text block. Is that the problem you're encountering?

Comment: Please note that the template you are using is very old (2007). Springer has a new template on their site with a new class `sn-jnl`, which positions the `sidewaystable` in the center of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they support it. Because this is what it shows:
[image: LATEX Warning:]